# How to reset Autocomplete in react-hook-forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm working with [react-hook-forms](https://react-hook-form.com/) and trying to reset all form fields after submit. The problem is that in my case Autocomplete accepts objects as a value.

I've tried to set the `defaultValue` to `{}`, but received the following message:

> Material-UI: the `getOptionLabel` method of Autocomplete returned undefined instead of a string for
> {}

Are there any variants how Autocomplete could be reset?

Here is a link to the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-controller-nh78t?file=/src/MuiAutoComplete.js)

Comment: Hey Karen, have you seen this example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v6-controller-qsd8r which has an autocomplete.

Answer (score 2):

A little late to the party but here's a solution if anyone else needs it.

Assuming your autocomplete is wrapped inside a Controller, all you have to do is explicitly check the value in Autocomplete. Refer below for more

```
<Controller
name="category"
control={control}
rules={{ required: true }}
render={({ field }) => (
    <Autocomplete
        fullWidth
        options={categories}
        {...field}
        // =====================================================
        // Define value in here
        value={
            typeof field.value === "string"
                ? categories.find((cat) => cat === field.value)
                : field.value || null
        }
        // =====================================================
        onChange={(event, value) => {
            field.onChange(value);
        }}
        renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
                {...params}
                label={t("product_category")}
                error={Boolean(errors.productCategory)}
                helperText={errors.productCategory && "Product Category is required!"}
            />
        )}
    />
)}
/>
```

This should do the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I am suggesting you to do in this way

```
<Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      rules={{
        required: required,
      }}
      render={({
        field: { onChange, value, onBlur }, // Create a alias for onChange if it's confusing 
        fieldState: { error }
      }) => {
        return (
          <Autocomplete
            //Here never use the onInputChange
            options={options || []}
            getOptionLabel={(option) => {
              return option[optionLabel] ? option[optionLabel] : "";
            }} /* This [optionLabel] assume it like you want show it from the array  */
            getOptionSelected={(option, value) => {
              return option.id === value.id;
            }}
            value={value ?? ""} // This value is from the hook form
            inputValue={value?.[optionLabel] ?? value ?? ""} // here the option label is 'name'  Used nullish coalescing here
            onChange={(event, values, reason) => {
              if (reason === "clear") {
                onChange(null); // This onChange is from the Hook forms
                return;
              }
              onChange(values || null);
            }}
            renderInput={(params) => (
              <TextField
                {...params}
                label=label 
                variant="outlined"
                size="small"
                onChange={(event) => {
                  onChange(event.target.value); //Hooks onChange 
                }} // Kindly use the onchange here 
                InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }} // will help you to keep it as label always shrinked 
                error={errors[name] ? true : false}
                helperText={
                  errors[name]?.type === "serverError"
                    ? errors[name]?.message
                    : errors[name]?.type === "required"
                    ? label + " required"
                    : ""
                }
              />
            )}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
```

In here while OnChange(MUI) the input value will update on Hook form. That can be reflected in the inputValue = {value?.[optionLabel]}.
After you choose one value from the dropdown "Value" prop will be updated. After the reset() is triggered from the hook form All the values are become 'undefined'. If the value and value?.[optionLabel] both are undefined means nullish will choose the Empty string.

Hope it will be helpfull!

Answer (score 0):

To reset the value of `AutoComplete` with `reset` of react hook form you should add the `value` prop to the AutoComplete, other ways the reset wont function, see the example:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import {
  Autocomplete,
  TextField,
  reset,
} from '@mui/material'
...

const {
  ...
  setValue,
  control,
  formState: { errors },
} = useForm()

useEffect(() => {
  reset({
    ...
    country: dataEdit?.country ? JSON.parse(dataEdit?.country) : null,
  })
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, [dataEdit])


...
<Controller
  control={control}
  name="country"
  rules={{
    required: 'Veuillez choisir une réponse',
  }}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
    <Autocomplete
      value={value || null}
      options={countries}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
      onChange={(event, values) => {
        onChange(values)
        setSelectedCountry(values)
        setValue('region', null)
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          label="Pays"
          placeholder="Pays"
          helperText={errors.country?.message}
          error={!!errors.country}
        />
      )}
    />
  )}
/>
```

[image]